# Google Glass Voice Recognition breaks in XE 21.3

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I own a Google glass device with version XE 21.3. Two days back it got updated from 19.3 to 21.3.

In my previous 19.3 version, I was able to detect any word from within my application using this [library](https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets) that provided the `GlassVoice.jar` file.

However, when Glass got updated now, the complete app breaks and instead shows an Exception that says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: VoiceConfig versiom mistmatch. try pulling GlassVoice.apk`

I tried pulling out the .apk and converted to .jar again but the issue isn't resolved.

Can someone help or guide me to a solution?

Comment: are you sure that you are using the new .jar file while building your application?

Comment: yes I am using the new .jar . the new GlassVoice-xe21.0 jar...@pscholl: i have mailed u my complete problem at your address [scholl@ess.tu-darmstadt.de] please reply soon

Comment: You need to pull the latest GlassVoice.apk from Glass itself and convert it using dex2jar. Apparently the 21.0 (the one on github atm) version is not compatible with 21.3, so you need to redo this step. I can't remember where exactly the .apk is located, but you can use find to search for it...

Comment: I tried that...the apk is located at ./system/priv-app/GlassVoice.apk. I used dex2jar and added the .jar file thus obtained in my project but still it didnt work. Can you try out the same at your end. I can provide you the .jar if required. let me know your email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update the github repository with the newest GlassVoice.apk. For the next updates the usual route to get this working is (in the project root folder, replace ):

1. adb pull /system/priv-app/GlassVoice.apk
2. dex2jar -o lib/libs/GlassVoice-xe.jar GlassVoice.apk
3. edit lib/build.gradle to use the GlassVoice-xe.jar file
4. fix all build error in the voice helpers, i.e. fix the stuff that has changed from the last release.

Comment: hey @pscholl: I am using eclipse so then I need to add the .jar in the libs folder right? have you obtained the latest XE 21.3 jar ..since I have tried using your jar (which you have committed 24 days ago) but that does seem to work. In fact when I did use that my project just would compile and it would throw "GC overhead limit error" where as the previous jar would not throw an error

Comment: sorry, forgot to push the changes :) The GC overhead is probably due to the heap memory limit of eclipse, so you might want to increase that (https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F).

Comment: I will try using your updated .jar file and let you know asap

Comment: hey @pscholl I tried using your version but still it didn't work. I have increased the VM size to max 1024 M but the GC overhead error still persists. Have you tested this jar on your device? Are you using eclipse? If yes can you send me the sample project. Please email me on androidparth@gmail.com ..thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not using eclipse, for me building with gradle/android studio works fine and it works on the device.

Comment: is it necessary to use android studio? can you send me your complete project

Comment: The one on github is the complete project. You can either use gradle to build it (by using `./gradlew installDebug`) or importing it into android studio.

Comment: thanks @pscholl. It worked for me using Android studio. But can you please also upload a project for Eclipse since many developers still use Eclipse. If I have any further questions I will post it over here. thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: can you try and port the same project in Eclipse using the latest ADT?